# Basic question that has to do with exterior derivative.

Tags: differential-forms

Basic question:

If we have $$Y=d\left(\frac{1}{\alpha} +\frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}}\right)$$
where $d$ is exterior derivative, i.e, $Y$ is a $1$-form.

Now we could write that as

$$Y=d\left(\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{|\alpha|^2} + \frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|^2}\right)$$

where $|\alpha|^2=\alpha \bar{\alpha}$.

Can we simply the last equation to

$$Y=\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}d(\bar{\alpha}+\alpha)$$
or the presence of the exterior derivative does not allow us to move the now real function, $|\alpha|^2$, outside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that as the exterior derivative is not linear over functions. In general, if $f$ is a smooth function and $\omega$ is a $k$-form, $d(f\omega) = df\wedge\omega + fd\omega$ which you'll note is not the same thing as $fd\omega$.

Comment: Nicely said. Thank you, I see now!